# Improper rendering of numerical values while reading Wikipedia table in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read a content of a Wikipedia table in a pandas DataFrame.

```
In [110]: import pandas as pd

In [111]: df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_GDP")[0]
```

However, this dataframe contains gibberish values in certain columns:

```
                        0                            1                     2  \
0  City/Metropolitan area                      Country  Geographical zone[1]   
1                Aberdeen               United Kingdom       Northern Europe   
2                 Abidjan  Côte d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)                Africa   
3               Abu Dhabi         United Arab Emirates          Western Asia   
4             Addis Ababa                     Ethiopia                Africa   

                                    3  \
0     Official est. Nominal GDP ($BN)   
1  7001113000000000000♠11.3 (2008)[5]   
2                                 NaN   
3         7002119000000000000♠119 [6]   
4                                 NaN   

                                                   4  \
0  Brookings Institution[2] 2014 est. PPP-adjuste...   
1                                                NaN   
2                                                NaN   
3                          7002178300000000000♠178.3   
4                                                NaN   

                                         5  \
0  PwC[3] 2008 est. PPP-adjusted GDP ($BN)   
1                                      NaN   
2                   7001130000000000000♠13   
3                                      NaN   
4                   7001120000000000000♠12   

                                         6                             7  
0  McKinsey[4] 2010 est. Nominal GDP ($BN)  Other est. Nominal GDP ($BN)  
1                                      NaN                           NaN  
2                                      NaN                           NaN  
3                 7001671009999900000♠67.1                           NaN  
4                                      NaN                           NaN
```

For example, in the above dataframe in the column for `Official est. Nominal GDP`, the first entry is `11.3(2008)` but we see some big number before that. I thought that this must be problem with encoding and I tried passing `ASCII` as well as `UTI` encodings:

```
In [113]: df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_GDP", encoding = 'ASCII')[0]
```

However, even this doesn't solve the problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the invisible (in the browser) "sort key" elements:

```
<td style="background:#79ff76;">
    <span style="display:none" class="sortkey">7001130000000000000♠</span> 
    13
</td>
```

May be there is a better way to clean it up, but here is a working solution based on the idea of finding these "sort key" elements and [removing](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) them from the table, then let `pandas` parse the table HTML:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


response = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_GDP")
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable")
for span in table.select("span.sortkey"):
    span.decompose()

df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
print(df)
```

Comment: Not working. `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` error on line `table = soup.select_one()`

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi okay, are executing the code as is without any changes?

Comment: Yep. Copy paste. I'm on python2.7 but that won't make any difference I guess except the print statement.

Comment: Interesting, works for me on both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: BeautifulSoup version? Something to do with it?

Comment: @alecxe Don't have `soup.select_one()` method in my version :|

Comment: @MohammadYusufGhazi oh, might be pretty old version :) Update please: `pip install beautifulsoup4 --upgrade`.

Comment: Is `soup` alias for `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: @Peaceful nope, `soup` is an instance of the `BeautifulSoup` class.

Comment: Oops.. I didn't see that instance was created in the line before ;)

Comment: workaround did the job: `table = soup.select("table.wikitable")
table = BeautifulSoup(str(table[0]))
for span in table.select("span.sortkey"):
    span.decompose()`

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the HTML source of that page, you'll see that a lot of cells have a hidden `<span>` containing a "sortkey".  These are the strange numbers you're seeing.

If you look at [the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) for `read_html`, you'll see this:

> Expect to do some cleanup after you call this function. [...] We try to assume as little as possible about the structure of the table and push the idiosyncrasies of the HTML contained in the table to the user.

Put them together and you have your answer: garbage in, garbage out.  The table you're reading from has junk data in it, and you'll have to figure out how to handle that yourself.